# Where is the authentication generated by the first login in the spring stored?

Tags: spring, authentication, security, filter

Where is the authentication generated by the first login in Spring stored, so can I move the page in succession without additional login on the page that requires permission?

Looking at it while debugging, I wonder why the member function of AuthenticationProvider is called when you log in for the first time, but not after that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.